# How to find a specific row in csv

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv

I'm using ruby 1.9.2. My csv file as follows..,

```
NAME,    Id,   No,  Dept
Tom,     1,    12,   CS
Hendry,  2,    35,   EC
Bahamas, 3,    21,   IT
Frank,   4,    61,   EE
```

I want to print an specific row say ('Tom'). I tried out in many ways, but I didn't find the exact result. The most recommended options is "Fastercsv". But it is applicable for my version. Also, I noticed that csv print the field as column wise. How to print an entire row using csv in rails. My ruby code is as follows

```
require 'csv'

csv_text = File.read('sampler.csv')
csv = CSV.parse(csv_text, :headers => true)
csv.each do |row|
 puts "#{row[:NAME]},#{row[:Id]},#{row[:No]},#{row[:Dept]}"
end
```

Comment: Just a heads up that you can also use `CSV` to read in the `.csv` file directly, with `CSV.read( "sampler.csv", header: true )`.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

#### Use `.find`

```
csv = CSV.read('sampler.csv', headers: true)

puts csv.find {|row| row['NAME'] == 'Tom'} #=> returns first `row` that satisfies the block.
```

Comment: Thanks! This works because in this context, `csv` is an an array of arrays.  Arrays have the `Enumerable` module included, and `Enumerable` provides the `find` method.

Comment: a little gotcha: numbers still need to be enclosed in quotations like so 

`puts csv.find {|row| row['id_number'] == '0001'}`

Comment: Ah yeah, the gotchas of untyped languages. Everything's a string in csv files.

Comment: So what's returned from `find`? Is it the first row that matches the block's conditional?

Comment: I'll answer my own question, it returns the first `row` that satisfies the block.

Comment: Also edited the answer to not only show how `csv` is defined but to use `CSV.read` instead of `File.read` and then parsing the String.

Comment: I need to use `headers`, or I get ArgumentError (unknown keyword: header).

Comment: The correct keyword argument is `headers` instead of `header`.

Answer (score 6):

Here's another approach that keeps the code within the CSV API.

`csv_table` is a `CSV::Table`
`row` is a `CSV::Row`
`row_with_specified_name` is a `CSV::Row`.

```
csv_table = CSV.table("./tables/example.csv", converters: :all)
row_with_specified_name = csv_table.find  do |row|
    row.field(:name) == 'Bahamas'
end

p row_with_specified_name.to_csv.chomp #=> "Bahamas,3,21,IT"
```

FYI, `CSV.table` is just a shortcut for:

```
CSV.read( path, { headers:           true,
                  converters:        :numeric,
                  header_converters: :symbol }.merge(options) )
```

As per [the docs](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.1.0/CSV.html).

Comment: it says `undefined local variable or method `row_with_specified_name'`

Comment: I forgot the variable assignment. See the updated code sample in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a large CSV file and want to find an exact row it will be way faster and way less memory intense to read one line at a time.

```
require 'csv'

csv = CSV.open('sampler.csv', 'r', headers: true)

while row = csv.shift
  if row['name'] == 'Bahamas'
    break
  end
end

pp row
```

Comment: This answer is indeed more performant.